# AWS Java SDK STS in Lambda timeout

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk, aws-sts

I want to get temporary credentials via AWS Security Token Service in Lambda, but it is timeout at `AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build()` all the time.

Does anyone help me?

Source Code:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleResult;

public class SecurityTokenService implements RequestHandler<Request, Credential> {

    public Credential handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                .withPolicy("arn:aws:iam::12345678900:policy/SomePolicy")
                .withDurationSeconds(900);

        AWSSecurityTokenService securityTokenService = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().build();

        AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = securityTokenService.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);

        return new Credential(assumeRoleResult.getCredentials());

    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2018-02-22T09:12:55.102Z 8f49ee0a-17b0-11e8-892f-753d21bb516c Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

Comment: The *first* things to try are to increase your function timeout to an unreasonably large value, such as 60 seconds, to be certain that this isn't simply a case where your code requires more than 3 seconds to initialize in a new container, and increasing the allowed memory because it has the side effect of also increasing the available CPU cycles to the container (speeding up CPU-bound processes).

Comment: It works! Thanks.
I tried set timeout  to 10 seconds, yesterday. It is timeout. Then I stop trying. I should try more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with default memory settings of 128 MB. After increasing memory to 512 MB it works now.